# Why does Stack Overflow not use a X-UA-Compatible meta tag?

Tags: feature-request, internet-explorer

Is there a reason why Stack Overflow does not use a X-UA-Compatible meta tag?

At my work we are forced to use Internet Explorer 10 with no access to the options, this forces Internet Explorer into IE10 Compatibility mode while browsing Stack Overflow. To get around this issue I need to open Developer tools and change the Browser Mode to IE10 mode every time.

Would it be possible to implement `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` or would this cause some detriment to the site?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way we'd do this is by adding a *header* which has much better performance characteristics since when IE encounters the meta tag it must stop and restart the parse with the correct engine rather than doing a single correct pass with the header knowledge ahead of time.

That being said - I don't believe there is such a need. Your viewing IE10 is compatibility mode is definitely not normal, and whatever is causing it to do so should be the fix. We're all about fixing root causes, not symptoms here.

Does your network deploy some non-standard IE rules and/or compatability mode lists that Stack Overflow is on?